# Alternate method to write the If method in the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, iif

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [User].GetUserByEmail
    @Email VARCHAR(200),
    @GetActiveOnly BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@GetActiveOnly = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            portalUser.PortalUserId AS 'UserId',
            organisation.OrganisationId AS 'OrganisationId',
            organisation.LookUpOrganisationTypeId AS 'OrganisationTypeId'
        FROM    
            Admin.PortalUser portalUser
        INNER JOIN 
            Admin.LookUpPortalUserRole userRole ON userRole.LookUpPortalUserRoleId = portalUser.LookUpPortalUserRoleId
        INNER JOIN 
            Admin.Organisation organisation ON organisation.OrganisationId = portalUser.OrganisationId
        WHERE   
            portalUser.Email = @Email
            AND portalUser.IsActive = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            portalUser.PortalUserId AS 'UserId',
            organisation.OrganisationId AS 'OrganisationId',
            organisation.LookUpOrganisationTypeId AS 'OrganisationTypeId'
        FROM    
            Admin.PortalUser portalUser
        INNER JOIN 
            Admin.LookUpPortalUserRole userRole ON userRole.LookUpPortalUserRoleId = portalUser.LookUpPortalUserRoleId
        INNER JOIN 
            Admin.Organisation organisation ON organisation.OrganisationId = portalUser.OrganisationId
        WHERE   
            portalUser.Email = @Email 
    END
END
```

In the above stored procedure, when `@Getactiveonly` is true, then it should take only the users who are active else it should take both active and inactive users. i.e `IF (@GetactiveOnly = 1)` then it will fetch users  whose `Isactive` is 1 only else it fetches all the users whose `IsActive` is 0 as well 1.

Could this be written in a simpler way to avoid duplication of select statements?

Comment: As @Peter had answered yes it's possible. I only advice you check the query plans for both versions. Sometimes OR may lead to problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply some more boolean logic, leading to this unified query:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE portalUser.Email = @Email
AND (@GetActiveOnly = 0 OR portalUser.IsActive = 1)
```

In words:

- For 0, the first part is TRUE, making the second part irrelevant.
- For 1, the first part is FALSE and then the second part determines the outcome.